# bq command not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am currently working on windows machine. Installed WSL to be able to work in Linux env.

Installed the Google Cloud SDK and am able to run gsutil and gcloud commands.
However, while trying to run `bq`, I get the bq command not found error.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Hi there! How do you installed Google Cloud SDK? You installed Google Cloud SDK using a package manager like **APT** or **DNF** ?  The installation defines how you should add other components to your Cloud SDK. Take a look to [Managing SDK Components](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components) page. So, you can not find `bq` command since it’s not installed.

Comment: Clarify your problem. You mention Windows and WSL, which one? The **bq** command is installed in the same location as **gcloud**.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar issue when working on a Windows environment. I have found that calling `bq.cmd` helps to get the BigQuery commands to execute.

So running:
**`bq.cmd ls`**
instead of running:
`bq ls`

To list datasets in your current project.

Comment: How exactly did you call it?

Comment: Works for me (not using WSL but MinGW). As @nReyna stated: simply replace "bq" with "bq.cmd"

Answer (score 1):

"bq" is one of the default Cloud SDK components, and gets installed by [default](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#whats_in_the_box).

Please check with the command "gcloud components list" to confirm if "bq" is [available](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#listing_components).

If not, maybe somehow your installation got corrupted. Please try re-installing to fix this issue.

Otherwise, try running these [commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iAOZ.png), see how the path for all are set and same like "/usr/bin" in the given example. This may reveal some path setting related issues which need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In WSL2, install the Google Cloud CLI with this command as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#linux-mac).

`curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`

Then restart your WSL installation.  The `bq` command works at both a Windows command prompt and a WSL terminal.